# Where clause - Not Like Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i got a statement where i got a where clause like this:

```
AND  (  (ROOT_CAUSE_CODE like 'X%' OR ROOT_CAUSE_CODE like 'D%') AND (SUMMARY_DESC like 'COMPLETE%' or SUMMARY_DESC like 'MULTIPLE%') and SERVICE_LEVEL='TOP' and SERVICE_AFFECTED='1'  )
```

Now i want to create a second query, where i get exactly the opposite of those values of the first where clause. So i will use same statment but with a where clause which gives me all the values not like the first where clause?

How can i achieve that?

THX and BR
Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that none of the columns are `NULL`, then the opposite is:

```
AND NOT ( (ROOT_CAUSE_CODE like 'X%' OR ROOT_CAUSE_CODE like 'D%') AND
          (SUMMARY_DESC like 'COMPLETE%' or SUMMARY_DESC like 'MULTIPLE%') and
          SERVICE_LEVEL = 'TOP' and SERVICE_AFFECTED = '1'
       )
```

If the values can be `NULL` than the logic is more complicated.